# Google Drive API not listing latest files

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I'm still fairly new to programming and to the Google APIs specifically, but as far as I can tell my code should work as intended, but isn't.

I am using node.js with the googleapis module to access the Google Drive API, v3.

I am using the following to attempt to get a list of the latest 10 files in the drive, sorted from new to old:

```
drive.files.list({
  corpora: 'user',
  pageSize: 10,
  orderBy: 'modifiedTime desc'
  fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, owners, modifiedTime, mimeType, parents, size, thumbnailLink, webViewLink, originalFilename)', (err, res) => { ... });
```

This - with some code handling `res` - correctly outputs a list of files from my drive *and* the "shared with me" drive that is actually of interest, but the latest file it lists has a modifiedTime of `2020-04-08Tetc.`. When I look at the actual drive in a browser, the latest file is from May 15, 2020.

I did try to change `corpora` to "allDrives" with the requisite supportsAllDrives and includeItemsFromAllDrives (to be deprecated June 1st, 2020), but that did not change anything.. I didn't really expect it to, considering it does list files from the "shared with me" drive already.

I also tried to use `q: "not name contains 'QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ'"` to see if forcing an explicit search for files would help, but no such luck.

I did also look at the Activity API much earlier, but given the limited amount of details available, while also giving me information I did not need, I went with the drive.files.list approach so as to not have to make several separate API calls.

Am I going wrong in the code?
Is it a quirk where 'my' copy of the "Shared with me" Drive needs to be refreshed somehow?
Is the Google Drive API being silly?

Thank you so much for your help!

Edit: Per a suggestion, I tried with "Try this API" (aka API Explorer) and it, too, does not return the latest files. It matches my results exactly.

Edit 2: The Drive Activity API also does not list these recent files.  *However*, if I view a file explicitly (e.g. in a browser), it starts appearing in both API responses. What am I missing?

Edit 3: Corrected 'Shared Drive' to 'Shared with me Drive'. Also noticed that the Google Drive web interface itself shows "no recorded activity" for the files that the API is missing.

Comment: If you think that your problem comes from the coding implementaiton rather than the request logic - test first with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to see if your request there gives you the desired results.

Comment: good suggestion, @ziganotschka - tried the API explorer.. it, too, does not return the latest files (matching what I'm getting).

Comment: Maybe there is a confusion between `createdTime`,  `modifiedTime` and `modifiedByMeTime`?

Comment: I tried the various options, and none helped at all, except for ``viewedByMeTime``. With that item, the 'folder' of files that was added to the Shared Drive was visible, but not any of the files.  When I explicitly viewed one of the files, it showed with ``viewedByMeTime`` *and* with ``modifiedTime``.

I did also try the Drive Activity API, and it also fails to list the recent file changes (other than that 1 file I explicitly viewed in a browser).

I must be missing something, but I can't imagine what.

Comment: Are you looking for files in a shared drive or 'shared with me' (not the same)?

Comment: ugh, right, Google's naming schemes. Thank you for your patience in this.

This is a "Shared with me" Drive, not a drive that *I* shared.

For what it's worth, it looks like the Google Drive interface itself has issues with it, as it lists "no activity" for the files I haven't explicitly opened, not even an 'uploaded' event.